# Range update in Binary Indexed Tree

Tags: range, binary-indexed-tree

How can I use Binary Indexed Tree for range update such that each element `A[k]` in a range say `[i..j]` is updated to `A[k]*c` where `c` is some constant.

And I need to do point queries after such update operations.

I tried with the function below but it wasn't working, here `n` is size of array,`c` is the constant I want to multiply each element of range with.

```
def updateM(x, c, n):
while x <= n:
    BIT[x] *= c
    x += (x & -x)
```

and these are my calls to update the range:

```
updateM(i, c, n)
updateM(j+1, -c, n)
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicative inverse of `c` is not `-c` but `1/c`. Also, I don't understand, what you're trying to accomplish by `x += (x & -x)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You just have to run a loop.

But this method is over kill.

It would be best to use segment tree and update the appropriate range, not just a single value.